# How can my ViewController know when the user pushes the "back" button?

Tags: ios, swift

```
[A] -> Show Segue -> [B]
```

Everything is inside a navigation controller.  When the user pushes the back button on "B", how can it know? I want to perform an action (save profile) immediately when the user pushes back.

Answer (score 0):

The UIViewController class has a function called [willMoveToParentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:). I would try using that to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    print("back button was pressed")    
    saveMyProfile()
}
```

Something like that should hopefully do the trick.

Comment: This method is called when a view controller is added to another view controller and when it is removed from another view controller.

Comment: he could check for isBeingDismissed, and only save when the viewController is being dismissed.

Comment: `isBeingDismissed` can't be used inside `willMoveToParentViewController`.

Comment: well what about if parent.isBeingPresented == true ....that way you're checking against the given parent variable

Comment: `isBeingPresented` can't be used inside `willMoveToParentViewController`.

Comment: you can use it inside `willMoveToParentViewController` i just tried it

Comment: The documentation states it is only valid inside `viewWill|DidAppear`. Perhaps `willMoveToParentViewController` is being called from inside those methods.